# Get Extent of Multiple Shapefiles (Batch Process)

Tags: pyqgis, extents

I have 1000+ Shapefiles and want to get extent of these polygon shapefiles.
I know the manual way to do so.. Is there any way to do it through Script .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- For shapefiles **loaded** into QGIS, you can use the following in the *Python Console*:

  ```
  for layer in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values():   
      extent = layer.extent()
      xmin = extent.xMinimum()
      xmax = extent.xMaximum()
      ymin = extent.yMinimum()
      ymax = extent.yMaximum()
      print layer.name() + "|| xmin: %f, xmax: %f, ymin: %f, ymax: %f"% (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
  ```

---

- For shapefiles **not loaded** into QGIS (i.e. in a folder), you can use the following in the *Python Console*:

  ```
  import glob, os
  folder = "path/to/folder"
  for layer in glob.glob(folder + "*.shp"):
      layerName = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(layer))[0]
      layer = QgsVectorLayer(layer, layerName, "ogr")
      extent = layer.extent()
      xmin = extent.xMinimum()
      xmax = extent.xMaximum()
      ymin = extent.yMinimum()
      ymax = extent.yMaximum()
      print layerName + "|| xmin: %f, xmax: %f, ymin: %f, ymax: %f"% (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
  ```